# My android app is not being updated on the Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

**EDIT: Even though this question has been put on hold, I figure that I should update it since more than a few people have emailed me with similar issues since I put this up. Google finally did get back to me and admitted that there is a problem with the Play Store, and it required some manual intervention from them to get the updates going again. I am now beginning to see some new users with the latest build, and the app description has also been updated. If your app is misbehaving in a similar manner, your only option is to get in touch with Google by navigating through the maze of contact options.**

I have had an app on the Play Store since last December and have been publishing updates to 
it without any problems. However, for some reason my last update still hasn't shown up on the Play Store, even though it has been 3 days since I uploaded it.

As a test I tried just updating the description of the app. Even that hasn't reflected on the Store after 3 days.

Here is a list of uploaded APKs, from my developer console. It shows that I've uploaded builds on Apr 13 and Apr 16.
[developer console http://awaaz.mobi/so/dates.png](http://awaaz.mobi/so/dates.png)

And here is the public listing of my app on the Play Store. It shows that my app was last updated on Apr 2 -
[play store listing http://awaaz.mobi/so/play.png](http://awaaz.mobi/so/play.png)

Any clue why this might be happening? I've written to support, but haven't heard anything in the last 48 hours.

Comment: April 19th now, and I still don't see any update on the Store. Have written to Google support twice, but haven't heard anything from them either.

Comment: April 21st, still nothing

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about 3rd party app listings.

Comment: What do you mean by "3rd party app listing"? It's a problem with my app being listed on the Google Play Store.

Comment: The problem is that this looks like it is entirely a non-programming issue between yourself and Google. If Google have broken it there's nothing a bunch of random programmers on the Internet can do to help. If it is a programming issue we can help with you'd need to show more details than just screenshots of a website.

Comment: Even though this question has been put on hold, I figure that I should update it since more than a few people have emailed me with similar issues since I put this up.

Google finally did get back to me and admitted that there is a problem with the Play Store, and it required some manual intervention from them to get the updates going again. I am now beginning to see some new users with the latest build, and the app description has also been updated. If your app is misbehaving in a similar manner, your only option is to get in touch with Google by navigating through the maze of contact options.

Comment: Thanks Anuj, I am then contacting google.