# Google Play Store apk update

Tags: android, updating, android-install-apk

I had updated my apk file and build a new version (upgrading the versionCode and versionName).
The files was successfully uploaded on the apk 2 days back, but still it is not updated :(
Can some one pls help me.
Its still showing "Processing update" as status on the console.

I tried un-publishing the app and re-publishing the same, it made thing even worse.
Now M unable to search my application.

Tried contacting the google guys, but still no progress.

Please help

Found a similar qstn here

[My android app is not being updated on the Google Play Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23121895/my-android-app-is-not-being-updated-on-the-google-play-store)

Answer (score 0):

For a new app you need to have patience. It may take anything from 2 days to a week. There will be reviews and automated policy checks etc happening after which it will be available on store.

By republishing you just restarted the whole process.

Answer (score 0):

Usual process may take maximum one week. Here only you can do is wait till they respond.
The chances are there the app may be rejected for the update, due to some technical reason. Keep on checking the status change. Also create a query to Google.